# Binding a javascript object to another object on a different path, ngOptions

Tags: angularjs

```
var user = {
 vetClinics: [{name: "VetsRUs",...},...],
 pets: [{name: "Lassy", vetClinic: ??},...]
}
```

Say I have a user with many pets and he goes to a standard vet clinic for his dogs but goes to a specialized clinic for his Iguana.

Using angular, I want to be able to provide a select box that the user can associate each pet with any one of the clinics the user has registered in their system. Angular has a select directive with ngOptions attribute that I can point to the list of clinics.. Great.

When this data goes through the ser/deser dance via an api, that **link** that was made with the angular select box is broken. I can **rebind** these entities in an imperative style based on their identity and the select box will work again.

What's a better way of doing this? Is there any way I instruct angular that these objects are equal and so it will do the appropriate binding?

Edit 1: What my ngOptions markup looks like

```
<div ng-repeat="pet in user.pets">
            <label>{{pet.name}}</label>
            <select ng-model="pet.vetClinic"
                    ng-options="vc.name for vc in user.vetClinics"
                    ng-change="updateUserResource()"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your controller look like right now?

Comment: @ZackArgyle to simplify things lets say that I have one main ctrl with one object on its $scope: the user object as described above. user would be a $resource that is loaded when the user is authenticated. What needs clarification?